# Does Go sanitize URLs for web requests?

Tags: web, go

I was implementing a simple web server in Go. As I have no experience in web development, this striked as a serious question for me.

Let's say I'm serving web pages with a modified `loadPage` function from [here](http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/)

```
func loadPage(title string) []byte {
    filename := title 
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    return body
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    content := loadPage(req.URL.Path[1:])
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", content)
}
```

Technically this allows me to write a request in a form of

```
 http://example.com/../../etc/passwd
```

and the code would happily serve the /etc/passwd file, but it does not. Does this mean that there is some sort of protection against `../` in the Go http package or http protocol itself, or am I just doing something wrong and it is a security hole?

Comment: Better to use the built-in fileserver: `http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer`. Apart from protecting you from malicious requests like you're worried about, it'll also serve the files with right mime types.

Comment: @Anonymous this was just an example for the specific quests, I'm actually doing a lot more with the request.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`net/http` does this in its HTTP request multiplexer, [`ServeMux`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux):

> ServeMux also takes care of sanitizing the URL request path, redirecting any request containing . or .. elements to an equivalent .- and ..-free URL.

The relevant function is the private func `cleanPath(p string) string`, which [calls `path.Clean`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/server.go?s=40985:41006#L1407):

```
1415        np := path.Clean(p)
```

`path.Clean` [does the appropriate removals](http://golang.org/src/pkg/path/path.go?s=2443:2895#L89):

```
 97         case path[r] == '.' && path[r+1] == '.' && (r+2 == n || path[r+2] == '/'):
 98             // .. element: remove to last /
 99             r += 2
100             switch {
101             case out.w > dotdot:
102                 // can backtrack
103                 out.w--
104                 for out.w > dotdot && out.index(out.w) != '/' {
105                     out.w--
106                 }
```

There's an additional case if the path isn't rooted, but `cleanPath` above ensures it is so, by prepending a forward-slash to the path to be cleaned if there isn't one already.

Comment: It is interesting that `cleanPath` checks for empty string and prepending a slash because that seems to not be possible as input to the function.